# Problemas com Matriz bidimensionais de strings

Tags: c, matriz, dev-c++

Meu objetivo nesse exercício é que em cada loop para fazer um novo pedido de lanche, seja acrescentado na tabela final (matriz[i][j]) os dados informados.
No segundo "for" é onde eu tento atribuir as variáveis [int cod] [char lanche] [int preco] pra dentro da matriz. Acredito que haja uma incompatibilidade de variaveis, porém mesmo substituindo as variáreis por "texto" continua dando errado.
Resumindo, preciso de ajuda a identificar o erro e se possível, me indicar uma alternativa para resolver a incompatibilidade entre a matriz e as variáveis que quero colocar nela. Desde já agradeço a todos. (minha primeira pergunta aqui no Stack  o/).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

int cod, preco, total, quant, cont, i, j;
char lanche[100], matriz[i][j], novo_pedido;

total=0;
cont=1;
for(i=0; i<cont; i++){          
            puts("+--------+-------------------+----------------+");
            puts("| Código |      Lanche       |   Preço Unit.  |");
            puts("+--------+-------------------+----------------+");
            puts("|  100   |  Cachorro Quente  |    R$ 5,00     |");
            puts("|  101   |  Bauru Simples    |    R$ 6,00     |");
            puts("|  102   |  Bauru com Ovo    |    R$ 8,00     |");
            puts("|  103   |  Hamburguer       |    R$ 5,00     |");
            puts("|  104   |  Cheeseburger     |    R$ 7,00     |");
            puts("|  105   |  Refrigerante     |    R$ 2,00     |");
            puts("+--------+-------------------+----------------+");

            puts("\n\n+---------------Faça seu Pedido---------------+");

            cod=1;

            do{

            printf("Código do Lanche: ");
            scanf("%d", &cod);

                if(cod==100){
                    total=(total+5);
                    strcpy(lanche,"Cachorro Quente  ");
                }else if(cod==101){
                    total=(total+6);
                    strcpy(lanche,"Bauru Simples    ");
                }else if(cod==102){
                    total=(total+8);
                    strcpy(lanche,"Bauru com Ovo    ");
                }else if(cod==103){
                    total=(total+5);
                    strcpy(lanche,"Hamburguer       ");
                }else if(cod==104){
                    total=(total+7);
                    strcpy(lanche,"Cheeseburger     ");
                }else if(cod==105){
                    total=(total+2);
                    strcpy(lanche,"Refrigerante     ");
                }else{
                    puts("\n**Código Inválido!**\n");
                }
            }while ((cod<100)||(cod>105));

            printf("Quantidade: ");
            scanf("%d", &quant); getchar();

            puts("+---------------------------------------------+");

    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
        if(j==0){
            matriz[i][j]="cod";
        }
        if(j==1){
            matriz[i][j]="lanche";
        }
        if(j==2){
            matriz[i][j]="preco";
        }
    }       

            printf("Deseja realizar outro pedido? ");
            fflush(stdin);
            novo_pedido=getchar();

                if(novo_pedido=='s'){
                    cont=cont+1;
                    system("cls");
                }

            puts("+---------------------------------------------+");
            puts("");

}

        puts("\n\n+-------------Resultado do Pedido-------------+");
        puts("| Código |      Lanche       |  Quantidade"); 

for (i=0; i<cont; i++){
    for (j=0; j<3; j++){        
        //printf("|   %d  |  %s|     %d\n", cod, lanche, quant);
        printf("%s", matriz[i][j]);
    }
}

        puts("+---------------------------------------------+");
        printf("|                     TOTAL  |   R$ %d,00", (total*quant));
        puts("\n+---------------------------------------------+\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como tem um codigo tao grande se logo no inicio tem um erro? `matriz[i][j]` nao pode definir uma matriz com variáveis.

Comment: Precisa de indicar se pretende fazer com memoria estática `matriz[100][100]` ou memoria dinamica `**matriz` usando depois a alocaçao de memoria

Comment: estava apenas reutilizando um código de um exercício pra testar o uso de matrizes e vetores, porém no meu curso nem cheguei nessa matéria ainda então estou estudando por conta.
Muito obrigado pelas ajuda, se conseguir arrumar eu posto o resultado.

Comment: Eu não consigo ajudar porque ainda não percebi muito o que quer. Já aprendeu sobre memoria dinamica? Posso armazenar a quantidade e codigo num vetor e o produto numa matriz? Colocar tudo numa matriz seria mais complicado

Comment: eu consegui, usando apenas vetores e ponteiros, outra hr implemento matrizes haha.

Answer (score 0):

Então, eu resolvi meu próprio exercício. Não fiz exatamente o que eu pedi na pergunta inicial, n usei matrizes bidimensionais, apenas vetores de strings e ponteiros retornando um resultado muito satisfatório pra mim. Caso ainda queiram contribuir ficarei contente.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <locale.h>

        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");


        int cod, codi[50], preco, pre[50], total, quant, quantidade[50], cont, i;
        char *lanche[10][100], novo_pedido;

        //do{
        total=0;
        cont=1;
            for(i=0; i<cont; i++){          
                        puts("+--------+-------------------+----------------+");
                        puts("| Código |      Lanche       |   Preço Unit.  |");
                        puts("+--------+-------------------+----------------+");
                        puts("|  100   |  Cachorro Quente  |    R$ 5,00     |");
                        puts("|  101   |  Bauru Simples    |    R$ 6,00     |");
                        puts("|  102   |  Bauru com Ovo    |    R$ 8,00     |");
                        puts("|  103   |  Hamburguer       |    R$ 5,00     |");
                        puts("|  104   |  Cheeseburger     |    R$ 7,00     |");
                        puts("|  105   |  Refrigerante     |    R$ 2,00     |");
                        puts("+--------+-------------------+----------------+");

                        puts("\n\n+---------------Faça seu Pedido---------------+");
                        //puts("+---------------------------------------------+");


                        do{

                        printf("Código do Lanche: ");
                        scanf("%d", &cod);

                            if(cod==100){
                                *lanche[i]="Cachorro Quente  ";
                                codi[i]=cod;
                                pre[i]=5;
                            }
                            else if(cod==101){
                                *lanche[i]="Bauru Simples    ";
                                codi[i]=cod;
                                pre[i]=6;
                            }
                            else if(cod==102){
                                total=(total+8);
                                *lanche[i]="Bauru com Ovo    ";
                                codi[i]=cod;
                                pre[i]=8;
                            }
                            else if(cod==103){
                                total=(total+5);
                                *lanche[i]="Hamburguer       ";
                                codi[i]=cod;
                                pre[i]=5;
                            }
                            else if(cod==104){
                                total=(total+7);
                                *lanche[i]="Cheeseburger     ";
                                codi[i]=cod;
                                pre[i]=7;
                            }
                            else if(cod==105){
                                total=(total+2);
                                *lanche[i]="Refrigerante     ";
                                codi[i]=cod;
                                pre[i]=2;
                            }
                            else{
                                puts("\n**Código Inválido!**\n");
                            }
                        }while ((cod<100)||(cod>105));

                        printf("Quantidade: ");
                        scanf("%d", &quant); getchar();

                        quantidade[i]=quant;
                        total=total+(pre[i]*quant);

                        puts("+---------------------------------------------+");



                        printf("Deseja realizar outro pedido? ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        novo_pedido=getchar();

                            if(novo_pedido=='s'){
                                cont=cont+1;
                                system("cls");
                            }

                        puts("+---------------------------------------------+");
                        puts("");
            }

                        //}while((novo_pedido=='s')||(novo_pedido=='S'));


                    puts("\n\n+-------------Resultado do Pedido-------------+");
                    puts("| Código |      Lanche       |  Quantidade"); 

            for (i=0; i<cont; i++){     
                    printf("|   %d  |  %s|     %d\n", codi[i], *lanche[i], quantidade[i]);
            }


                    puts("\n+---------------------------------------------+");
                    printf("|                     TOTAL  |   R$ %d,00", total);
                    puts("\n+---------------------------------------------+\n");


        return 0;
        }
```